# Using Roslyn, if I have an IdentifierNameSyntax, can I find the member type it refers to (field, property, method...)

Tags: metaprogramming, aop, roslyn

I am attempting to use the Roslyn SDK and `StackExchange.Precompilation` (thank you!) to implement aspect-oriented programming in C#6.  My specific problem right now is, starting with an `IdentifierNameSyntax` instance, I want to find the "member type" (method, property, field, var, etc.) that the identifier refers to.  (How) can this be done?

---

**Background:**

The first proof-of-concept I am working on is some good old design-by-contract.  I have a `NonNullAttribute` which can be applied to parameters, properties, or method return values.  Along with the attribute there is a class implementing the `StackExchange.Precompilation.ICompileModule` interface, which on compilation will insert null checks on the marked parameters or return values.

This is the same idea as PostSharp's `NonNullAttribute`, but the transformation is being done on one of Roslyn's syntax trees, not on an already compiled assembly.  It is also similar to Code Contracts, but with a declarative attribute approach, and again operating on syntax trees not IL.

For example, this source code:

```cs
[return: NonNull]
public string Capitalize([NonNull] string text) {
    return text.ToUpper();
}
```

will be transformed into this during precompilation:

```cs
[return: NonNull]
public string Capitalize([NonNull] string text) {
    if (Object.Equals(text, null)) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));

    var result = text.ToUpper();
    if (Object.Equals(result, null))
        throw new PostconditionFailedException("Result cannot be null.");
    return result;
}
```

(`PostconditionFailedException` is a custom exception I made to compliment `ArgumentException` for return values.  If there is already something like this in the framework please let me know.)

For properties with this attribute, there would be a similar transformation, but with preconditions and postconditions implemented separately in the `set` and `get` accessors, respectively.

---

The specific reason I need to find the "member type" of an identifier here is for an optimization on implementing postconditions.  Note in the post-compilation sample above, the value that would have been returned is stored in a local variable, checked, and then the local is returned.  This storage is necessary for transforming `return` statements that evaluate a method or complex expression, but if the returned expression is just a field or local variable reference, creating that temporary storage local is wasteful.

So, when the `return` statement is being scanned, I first check if the statement is of the form `ReturnKeyword`-`IdentifierSyntaxToken`-`SemicolonToken`.  If so, I then need to check what that identifier refers to, so I avoid that local variable allocation if the referent is a field or var.

**Update**
For more context, check out the project this is in reference to on [GitHub](https://github.com/JamesFaix/Traction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` to determine the symbol an identifier binds to.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo.Type` to obtain the TypeInfo and use it to explore the Type